# Many layouts of same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to show same `@item` in different ways.
For example if `@item.template == template1` - when I hit the "show" link - I see one layout.
For template2 I see another layout of same item etc. By layout I mean different font, different table design etc.

What is the best way to do this?

Right now I have two ideas: Either have a special table, where column1 is template name, and column2 is HTML, and then I just take HTML and insert `@item` content. Another idea is to have many `.haml` files, and make a choice in the controller using `render` command.

But I'm still not sure. Maybe you can suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with many layout files as it's easier to maintain, version and you can use partials and all that stuff. So something like this in the controller action:

```
render :layout => @item.template
```

Comment: where is it better to store images for each layout? e.g. folder1 for template1, folder2 for template2. under `assets/images/layouts/templatename`?

Comment: Can be. I guess that's really up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a class to the wrapping element to modify the design?

E.g.

```
<div class="item layout-<%= @item.template %>">
  <h2><%= @item.title %></h2>

  <table>
    <!-- table data here -->
  </table>
</div>
```

Then in your `.css` file

```
.item.layout-template1 {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

.item.layout-template2 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's good, but I think it's a little less flexible than having several views.